# pgfplots quadrics

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wonder whether it is possible to draw the three following quadric surfaces (cone, hyperboloids)

```
x^2+y^2-z^2=0

x^2+y^2-z^2=1

x^2+y^2-z^2=-1

(and the axis)
```

using `pgfplots` `3d` or TikZ as it is done in the following image

[image]

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Hi Brownian and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 13):

run it with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.8,viewpoint=50 60 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint,
  ngrid=20 20, incolor=red!30, fillcolor=blue!30}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\defFunction[algebraic]{f1}(u,v){u*cos(v)}{u*sin(v)}{u}
\defFunction[algebraic]{f3}(u,v){u*cos(v)}{u*sin(v)}{sqrt(u^2+1)}
\defFunction[algebraic]{f4}(u,v){u*cos(v)}{u*sin(v)}{-sqrt(u^2+1)}
\defFunction[algebraic]{f5}(u,v){u*cos(v)}{u*sin(v)}{sqrt(u^2-1)}
\defFunction[algebraic]{f6}(u,v){u*cos(v)}{u*sin(v)}{-sqrt(u^2-1)}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,base=-4 4 pi pi neg,function=f1]
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,function=f4,base=-1 4 pi pi neg,opacity=0.4]
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,function=f3,opacity=0.4]
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,function=f6,base=1 4 pi pi neg,
          fillcolor=red!30,incolor=blue!30,opacity=0.2]
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,function=f5,base=1 4 pi pi neg,opacity=0.2]
\gridIIID[Zmin=-4,Zmax=4](-4,4)(-4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `viewpoint=50 60 10 rtp2xyz`:

[image]

Comment: Although the OP asked specifically about PGF, I want to thank you for an amazing image! BTW: Where does the need for XeLaTeX arise?

Comment: @Dror: Maybe it is the simplest compilation method among others such as `pdflatex --shell-escape` with `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` combo.