# Draw 3D quadric surfaces

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

Hi I want to know how i can draw 3D quadric surfaces defined by equations ...

[image]

I tried using 3d-plot and tikz but was unable to make it work :/

Comment: looks a lot like: [pgfplots quadrics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66536) my answer there covers the last two surfaces in your table- the other options should follow easily enough

Comment: Also [`pst-3dplot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot) is worth having a look at.